# TI Nspire Python: eval_function

Tags: python, ti-nspire

Is there an example of how the eval_function works from the TI System Menu module?

I have attempted

```
s=eval_function("sin",0.5)
print(s)
```

but this code returns an error.

So does

```
s=eval_function("sin(0.5)",True)
print(s)
```

Thank you in advance,

Eddie

Comment: include the error along with the code itself.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Texas I
nstruments\TI-Nspire CX CAS Student Softwar
e\python\doc2\storing.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "python\doc1", line 19, in eval_function
TypeError: Variable must be a function

Answer (score 2):

You will need a user-defined function on the Notes or Calculator page to assign a name to the OS function, like this:

`ef(x) := sin(x)` or `Define ef(x) = sin(x)`

Example of Python script on the editor page:

```py
from ti_system import *

s = eval_function("ef", 0.5)

print(s)
```